# IOS 8.0 Send SMS Silently, without displaying the SMS window

Tags: xcode, sms, ios8, programmatically-created

I spent more then a week to figure out a way to send SMS internally without popping out the conformation message; however, I did not find a way out.
Some answers on the stackoverflow seems to work for earlier IOS. It seems that there is not a single way to send SMS internally without doing "jailbreak", "custom frameworks"
I still believe that there is a solution. Just waiting for the answers. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I seriously doubt you can do this with non-jailbroken iOS. I don't want my phone silently sending texts on my behalf, do you?

Comment: In any case, if you're asking how to accomplish this programmatically you'll need to show your attemps. If you're looking for a tool/library to accomplish this, it's offtopic...

Comment: Yes, it is serious; however, you should able to schedule some messages to send them in future. Like a birthday wish. There must be a way if programmer registers the app